# how to check checkbox whether true or false in angularjs using index value

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have checkbox inside the `ng-repeat` I want check whether checkbox is checked or not using their index value

## html

```
<div ng-repeat="Name in Names">
    <input type="checkbox" 
           ng-change="checkchange(Name .MaterialStream, $index)"
           ng-model="Name.MaterialStream" />
</div>
```

## controller

```
$scope.checkchange=function(index){
      $scope.Names[index].active='true';
}
```

Now I get correct value when I check the checkbox. I have to get active value is `true` but I have check means active should be change into `false` in my case it's `true` here I attached my code help how to do this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Also is there a reason you pass the `$index` instead of the actual model you want to change?

Comment: when i check the checkbox i want to show true else false using index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can bind `Name.active` directly without using `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="Name in Names">         
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Name.active" />
</div>
```

---

Since you are binding `Name.MaterialStream` to checkbox, you can set `Name.active` based on it in `ng-change`.

```
$scope.checkchange=function(index){
  $scope.Names[index].active = $scope.Names[index].MaterialStream;
}
```

Comment: there is no way show any new scope value like active?

Comment: @jose  In your code, by `$scope.Names[index].active='true';` you are trying to update `active` property. isn't it?

Comment: $scope.Names[0].active=true/false i create dynamic like this @Pengyy

Comment: @jose sorry.....not at all. maybe we should chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143769/angularjs-checkbox-ng-click

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972984/how-to-store-service-in-dropdown-after-page-refreshing-using-angularjs   @Pengyy help

Comment: still No  Pengyy

Comment: @jose ok, i'll take a look for it.

Comment: @help Penyy
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109725/how-to-splice-the-array-based-on-paritcular-value-using-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of your checkbox, you simply have to return the model itself.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="Name in Names">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkchange($index)"
           ng-model="Name.MaterialStream" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.checkchange=function(index){
    return $scope.Names[index].MaterialStream;
}
```

Note that I removed the first argument you passed to the `checkchange` function as it wasn't used before. In fact, before you checked the `index` variable but it wouldn't hold the real `$index`-value.

Comment: no @philip i need that active scope not use model name :(

Comment: That `active` attribute does not hold the value of your model though.

Comment: i create active scope in run time

Comment: I really do not see the point what you want to achieve. Do you want to have the `active` attribute hold the models state (true/false)? If so, you just need to change the ng-model as described in @Pengyys answer.

Comment: my ng-model is look like this how to i call
 ng-model="selection.id[BFMaterialStream.MaterialStream]"

Comment: That is completely off from what you posted before. If you want to access `Name.active`, just set it like so. I think you should share all of your code or at least more parts of it, because otherwise I don't see a way to solve your problem completely.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-model` is more than enough to store `true false` for checkbox, you don't require `$index` at all, but If you must do it by `$index`, then also you can utilize the `ng-model`.

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/untkhraw/) example out of your code.

**In addition:** in your above code, definition of `checkchange()` method doesn't accept the `first argument`, thats an issue. you shouldn't pass it if you not going to consume it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Solution . With working example

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.Names = [{value : true}, {value : true},{value : false},{value : false},{value : true}]
        $scope.toggleSelection = function(x,index,event) {
          // how to check if checkbox is selected or not
          //alert(index + ' is ' + event.target.checked);  
          $scope.Names[index].Active = $scope.Names[index].value;
        };
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="Name in Names">
   {{$index}}
   <input type="checkbox" id="" name="check_box" 
          value="{{x}}"
          ng-change="toggleSelection(x.value,$index,$event)"
          ng-model="Name.value" > {{Name.Active}}
  </div>
  
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```