# How to store service in "dropdown" after page refreshing using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

The function i stored the dropdown selected value in service and move the value from one place to another it working fine, but what i need is after refreshing the page dropdown will change to select but i need select value must be in dropdown i am using cookie also here i attached my code help how to do this

## Controller code

```
app.factory('StoreService', function() {
  return {
    storedObject:''
  };      
});

app.controller('UserNameShowCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$filter', '$cookieStore','StoreService', 
 function ($scope, $http, $window, $filter, $cookieStore,StoreService) {


$scope.FacilityDropValues=[ { value: 0, content: "First content" },
            { value: 1, content: "Second content" }]

   $scope.value=  $cookieStore.get('FacilityID');

        $scope.FacilityChange=function(){
            debugger;
                $scope.value = StoreService;
                $cookieStore.put("FacilityID", StoreService);
                 $cookieStore.put("FacilityID1", $scope.value.storedObject);

        };
```

## html

```
<select id="MaterialFacility"  
     class="form-control"   
     ng-change="FacilityChange(value.storedObject)"
     ng-model="value.storedObject" >

   <option value=''>Select</option>
   <option ng-repeat="FacilityDropValue in FacilityDropValues" 
       value="{{FacilityDropValue.value}}">{{FacilityDropValue.content}}</option>                                           
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can bind `ng-model` of `select` with `StoreService` directly.

```
<select id="MaterialFacility" 
   class="form-control"   
   ng-change="FacilityChange()"
   ng-model="StoreService.storedObject" >
```

and store `StoreService` at `ng-change` event.

```
$scope.FacilityChange=function(){
  debugger;
  // $scope.value = StoreService;
  $cookieStore.put("FacilityID", StoreService);
  $cookieStore.put("FacilityID1", StoreService.storedObject);
};
```

Comments: `$scope.value = StoreService;` doesn't make any sense since you are changing `$scope.value`, this line will overwrite what you have selected with blank.

**ADD:**

when using ng-repeat at `select`, you have to use `ng-selected="expression"` to set the default selected option

```
<select id="MaterialFacility"  
        class="form-control"   
        ng-change="FacilityChange(value.storedObject)"
        ng-model="value.storedObject" >

  <option value=''>Select</option>
  <option ng-repeat="FacilityDropValue in FacilityDropValues" 
          ng-selected="FacilityDropValue.value === value.storedObject"
          value="{{FacilityDropValue.value}}">{{FacilityDropValue.content}}</option>                                           

</select>
```

NOTE: since you are saying when binding StoreService directly in template leads to blank page and no error, here you san still bind with `value.storedObject`.

Comment: same after reload reload it's come to select @Pengyy

Comment: @jose what's your version of angularjs?

Comment: @jose see my answer of the `ADD` part.

Comment: but my values are stored in cookies correctly @pengyy

Comment: @jose it doesn't change much, just give it a try.

Comment: i try my whole page will not load just blank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144239/discussion-between-pengyy-and-jose).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45342577/ng-change-not-trigger-in-ie-11-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. you did not update the service, storeservice

```
Instead of 
 $scope.value = StoreService;
Use 
StoreService.storedObject =$scope.value.storedObject
```

Comment: same yar @RandyPrad

Comment: can you put the console and check what values is stroing store service

Comment: can you check the console and what it is storing in store service