# IE 11 is not triggering "ng-change" (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

Hi all I am using `angularjs`, working with `datepicker` functionality. Input type date is not working on IE so I am using `jquery` and `css` to get date picker, it's working fine but I am not able to trigger the `ng-change` event in IE, here I attached my fiddle help. Help me solving this problem.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/5083/)

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 does not currently support `<input type='date'>`. You may use ng-datepicker.

Comment: @ Ahmet Can Güven i know so only i apply date unsupported browser i apply jquery to get another picker kindly check my fiddle in IE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make <input type="date"> supported on all browsers? Any alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020950/how-to-make-input-type-date-supported-on-all-browsers-any-alternatives)

Comment: Please update your fiddle link with TTP. You are trying to load external resources from HTTPS, it may fail on some browsers because of security reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer 11 does not currently support `<input type='date'>` as you already trying to find a work around. You may use `datepicker onSelect` and update your model. You can fire change function manually. So that you can collect both changes from HTML5 Date supported browsers and others.

You can find the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/5091/)

```js
function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.changeDetected = function() {
        console.log($scope.date);
    }

    if ($('#test')[0].type != 'date') $('#test')
        .datepicker({
            onSelect: function(date) {
                $scope.date = date;
                $scope.$apply();
                $scope.changeDetected(date);
            }
        });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
 <input type="date" id="test" ng-model="date" ng-change="changeDetected()"/>
  {{date}}
</div>
```

Comment: fiddle no opening in IE

Comment: @jose Added fiddle link

Comment: i am not able trigger ng-change event still now or i need to that textbox dirty form true

Comment: @jose Edited fiddle for ng-change.

Answer (score 0):

Reason why it is not working is IE11 is not know to type="date"
Please have a look into the screenshot!!
https://iamlalit.tinytake.com/sf/MTgxNjMyN181OTAwMzE4

Comment: in my fiddle i apply css to get picker any way to solve that pblm

Answer (score 0):

**IE 11 does not support `<input type='date'>`.  So you can go with using input `type='text'` or [date picker](https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/).**

but anyway you need validate if the field has been entered invalid date from this discussion

[Javascript: how to validate dates in format MM-DD-YYYY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276479/javascript-how-to-validate-dates-in-format-mm-dd-yyyy)

---

and you should read these below discussions to better understand

[How to make <input type="date"> supported on all browsers? Any alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020950/how-to-make-input-type-date-supported-on-all-browsers-any-alternatives)

[How to get HTML 5 input type="date" working in Firefox and/or IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10)

Answer (score 0):

Below we are talking about IE11:

I think the reason is jquery .datepicker method won't delegate the date change to your ng-change method.

If you modify the input type="text", the ng-change also won't trigger the alert.
But if you modify the input content manually, it triggers the alert message.

Maybe you should use some angular datepicker instead of jquery date picker to handle all the browsers.